# htaccess 404 error on language subfolder (en/)

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, no-www

I have the following structure:

```
/  
/about.php  
/contact.php  
/en/  
/en/about.php  
/en/contact.php
```

And I want to remove .php extension and www prefix from the urls and force https as well.

Now I have the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php  
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$  
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't see the `lang` subfolder in your directory structure ..  What is your exact issue ...  In my opinion .. If you're trying to remove the `.php` extension in the way you have displayed here, it is going to fail when you try to view a subdirectory because what it's **looking** for is `example.com/lang`  is masking --> `example.com/lang.php`.  So in reality it's only telling you that `lang.php` doesn't exist.

Comment: That's exactly the issue. Subdirectories fail because of that approach. I tried several other versions but I'm not familiar with htaccess and I always have a broken website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close as far as what you have.  Now that I know the issue I'll give you what I use -- You need a condition that says **is not a directory** -- And the syntax is `!-d`

This is how **my** htaccess looks (because I use it to remove `html` as well as `php`:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# Redirect www and http to https - non-www
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Start php extension remove
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
# End php extension remove    

# Start html extension remove
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# End html extension remove
```

As you can see the first **condition** checks to see that it's not a directory.  The following **condition** checks to see if it's file extension is `.php`.  If both conditions are **true** -- The **rule** is to remove the extension.

As a note --  I would make your syntax a little cleaner and separate the "sections" of what you are trying to do.

**UPDATE AS PER COMMENT**

To remove the `https` forcing --  Simply comment out the first **condition** and change `https` to `http` in the **rule**:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# Redirect www and http to https - non-www
   #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Start php extension remove
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
# End php extension remove    

# Start html extension remove
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# End html extension remove
```

Comment: Thanks Zak for your quick reply. It works perfect and it looks a lot cleaner. 
Just a question. What should I edit to remove https force?

Comment: you can just comment out `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` -- And then change `RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` to `RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: I tried that earlier but I guess the htaccess file was cached so it didn't work. I tested it again on a clear browser and it works just fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again. I tried this htaccess on a new website and I have the following issue: When I point the en subdirectory I get the following message on the browser `The requested URL /en.php was not found on this server.`
Any ideas?